# Parent image of all list of thumbs created by Wordpress upload not getting the right permissions IIS

Tags: wordpress, image, iis, file-permissions

I have a wordpress on a windows server, when uploading images, wordpress create a collection of different sizes, ok, and all of then gets the rights permissions except for the parent one. This one doesn't get the user application group of the IIS permissions.

This is the list of permissions of each one, as you can see the parent one, doesn't get the "canicross" user permissions.

[image]

wp-content and temp folder have the right permissions.